# Problem updating flutter from 2.10.2 to 3.10.0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

When i execute my flutter application it don't install and get a lot of error after updating flutter from 2.10.2 to 3.10.0

: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
../…/src/google_fonts_base.dart:32
AssetManifest assetManifest = AssetManifest();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: No named parameter with the name 'window'.
../…/src/print_commands.dart:193
window: WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()
^^^^^^
: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
../…/rendering/view.dart:68
RenderView({
^^^^^^^^^^

: Error: Method not found: 'ViewConfiguration'.
../…/src/widget_wrapper.dart:174
configuration: ui.ViewConfiguration(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: No named parameter with the name 'window'.
../…/src/widget_wrapper.dart:173
window: _FlutterView(
^^^^^^
: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
../…/rendering/view.dart:68
RenderView({
^^^^^^^^^^

: Error: 'ViewConfiguration' isn't a type.
../…/src/widget_wrapper.dart:234
final ui.ViewConfiguration configuration;

```
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

: Error: No named parameter with the name 'kind'.
../…/core/photo_view_gesture_detector.dart:89
}) : super(debugOwner: debugOwner, kind: kind);

```
                                 ^^^^
```

: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:printing/src/fonts/manifest.dart'.
../…/fonts/font.dart:47
if (await AssetManifest.contains(asset)) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^

: Error: 'VoidCallback' isn't a type.
../…/utils/downloader_utils.dart:23
final VoidCallback onDone;

```
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Failed to compile application.

I already try flutter clean and flutter pub get